# Proving existence of generalized rectangle with desired volume

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that for each $\varepsilon>0$ and for each generalized rectangle $I$ in $\mathbb R^n$, there exists a generalized rectangle $J$ contained in the interior of $I$ such that $\text{vol } I - \text{vol } J < \varepsilon$. If $I$ has dimensions $I = \ell_1\times \ell_2\times\cdots\times \ell_n$ and for some $0<\delta<\ell_1$ I define $J$ to be a generalized rectangle inside of $I$ with dimensions $(\ell_1-\delta)\times\ell_2\times\cdots\times\ell_n$, then solving for $\delta$ is quite straightforward, but $J$ is not strictly in the interior of $I$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle \ell_{i}=[a_i,b_i]$. Define:

$$\ell'_{i}=[a_i+\delta,b_i-\delta]$$

Then $$\ell'_1\times\ell'_2\times\cdots\times\ell'_n$$

is a rectangle which you're looking for.The volume of this rectangle is:

$$V'=\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(b_i-a_i-2\delta)$$

Volume of rectangle original rectangle is $V$, for sufficient small $\delta$ you have:

$$|V'-V|<\varepsilon$$

How small $\delta$ should be?

Let's denote:

$$V'_{j}=\Pi_{i=j}^{n}(b_i-a_i)$$
$$V''_{j}=\Pi_{i=1}^{j}(\frac{b_i-a_i}{2}+V'_{j+1})$$

Note that if $n=1$ it's trivial, if we put $\displaystyle \delta_n<\frac{\varepsilon}{V''_{n}2^{n+1}}$, then:

$$(b_n-a_n)-(b_n-a_n-2\delta_n)<\frac{\varepsilon}{V''_{n}2^{n}}$$

Let's construct $\delta_{j}$ from $\delta_{j+1}$ that:

$$\Pi_{i=j}^{n}(b_i-a_i)-\Pi_{i=j}^{n}(b_i-a_i-2\delta_j)<\frac{\varepsilon}{V''_{j}2^{j}}$$
Put

$$\delta_{j}=\min\left(\delta_{j+1},\frac{\varepsilon }{2^{j}V''_{j}}\right)$$
Then we have:

$$\Pi_{i=j}^{n}(b_i-a_i)-\Pi_{i=j}^{n}(b_i-a_i-2\delta_j)=\\=(b_j-a_j)V'_{j+1} - (b_j-a_j-2\delta_{j})\Pi_{i=j+1}^{n}(b_i-a_i-2\delta_j) = \\ =(b_j-a_j)(V'_{j+1}-\Pi_{i=j+1}^{n}(b_i-a_i-2\delta_j))+2\delta \Pi_{i=j+1}^{n}(b_i-a_i-2\delta)< \\ <(b_j-a_j)\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{j+1}V''_{j+1}}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{j}V''_{j+1}}V'_{j+1}< \\ <\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{j}V''_{j}}$$

Finally just put $\delta=\delta_0$.

Comment: Right, but I would like to quantify how small $\delta$ should be.. in terms of the $a_i$ and $b_i$...

Comment: I've added sample estimation for $\delta$.